# How to do Pandas lstrip based on a condition?

Tags: python, pandas, string

I'm trying to do a strip operation on a pandas dataframe as below.

```
k = pd.DataFrame()
k['col'] = ['0', '0180', '190', '10', '0300']
k['col'].str.lstrip('0')
```

The result looks as below

```
0       
1    180
2    190
3     10
4    300
Name: col, dtype: object
```

However I would like the result to retain the single 0 in the first row and need the result look as below.

```
0      0
1    180
2    190
3     10
4    300
Name: col, dtype: object
```

I tried using a list comprehension but it filters out value 0

```
[item.lstrip('0') for item in k['col'] if len(item)>1 ]
output:
['180', '190', '10', '300']
```

How do I go about this? Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with `np.where`

```
k['new'] = np.where(k.col.str.len()>1,k.col.str.lstrip('0'),k.col)
k
Out[49]: 
    col  new
0     0    0
1  0180  180
2   190  190
3    10   10
4  0300  300
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.replace` with a regex pattern for more flexibility:

```
# replace all leading zeros 
# until the first non-zero character
k['col'].str.replace('^(0+)([^0])',r'\2')
```

Output:

```
0      0
1    180
2    190
3     10
4    300
Name: col, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try `k['col'].astype(int)`? .astype coerces your series to an int, preserving your 0, if it's significant.

```
np.array(['0', '0180', '190', '10', '0300']).astype(int)
array([  0, 180, 190,  10, 300])
```